# Methods in calling a service in Angular ng testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Hi Im new to Angular and Im having some hard time fixing this issue in my unit test script.
Im getting this error "Error: Expected spy createOperator to have been called."

Can you please give me some advice on how to correctly do this? Some example will do

btw my angular version is v16.14

**Unit test:**

```
describe('ComponentA', () => {
  let component: ComponentA;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ComponentA>;
  let ServiceA: ServiceA;
  let toast: ToastService;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        ComponentA
      ],
      imports: [
        TestingModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
          useValue: {
            user: {},
            companyId: 1
          }
        },
        {
          provide: MatDialogRef,
          useValue: {
            close: () => of(true)
          }
        }
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ComponentA);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    ServiceA = TestBed.inject(ServiceA);
    el = fixture.debugElement;
    toast = TestBed.inject(ToastService);
  }));

  fit('should create operator', () => {
    component.data.user = null;
    component.user = null;

    fixture.detectChanges();

    const payload = {
      user: {
        first_name: 'Test',
        last_name: 'Tester', 
        email: 'testy@yahoo.com',
      },
      roles: [
        [['operator'],],
      ]
    };

    component.userForm.patchValue(payload);

    const response = {
      status: 'success',
      code: 201,
      message: 'Successfully Created a Operator!'
    };
    
    spyOn(ServiceA, 'createOperator').withArgs(payload).and.returnValue(of(response));
    const submitSpy = spyOn(component, 'onSubmit').and.callThrough();
    const toastSpy = spyOn(toast, 'notifyAction')
      .and
      .callThrough();

    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.onSubmit();

    
    expect(ServiceA.createOperator).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(toastSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});
```

**component:**

```
onSubmit(): any {
  if (this.userForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }

  this.loading = true;
  const values = this.userForm.value;

  if (this.user?.id) {

    const payload = {
      user: {
        email: values.email,
      },
    };

    return this._applyService
      .updateOperatorUser(this.user.id, payload)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._subscription))
      .subscribe(
        (res: BasicResponse) => this.onSuccess(res),
        (err: BasicResponse) => this.onError(err)
      );
  }

  const payload = {
    user: {
      first_name: values.first_name,
      last_name: values.last_name,
      email: values.email,
    },
    roles: [
      values.role
    ]
  };

  return this._applyService
    .createOperator(payload)
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._subscription))
    .subscribe(
      (res: BasicResponse) => this.onSuccess(res),
      (err: BasicResponse) => this.onError(err)
    );
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What you have seems to be correct. I will try helping you to debug the issue with `console.log`s. Follow comments with !!.

```
onSubmit(): any {
  if (this.userForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }

  this.loading = true;
  const values = this.userForm.value;

  if (this.user?.id) {

    const payload = {
      user: {
        email: values.email,
      },
    };

    return this._applyService
      .updateOperatorUser(this.user.id, payload)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._subscription))
      .subscribe(
        (res: BasicResponse) => this.onSuccess(res),
        (err: BasicResponse) => this.onError(err)
      );
  }

  const payload = {
    user: {
      first_name: values.first_name,
      last_name: values.last_name,
      email: values.email,
    },
    roles: [
      values.role
    ]
  };
  console.log('!! Here !!'); // add this log and make sure you see it
  return this._applyService
    .createOperator(payload)
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._subscription))
    .subscribe(
      (res: BasicResponse) => this.onSuccess(res),
      (err: BasicResponse) => this.onError(err)
    );
}
```

```
fit('should create operator', () => {
    component.data.user = null;
    component.user = null;

    fixture.detectChanges();

    const payload = {
      user: {
        first_name: 'Test',
        last_name: 'Tester', 
        email: 'testy@yahoo.com',
      },
      roles: [
        [['operator'],],
      ]
    };

    component.userForm.patchValue(payload);

    const response = {
      status: 'success',
      code: 201,
      message: 'Successfully Created a Operator!'
    };
    
    // !! Remove `withArgs` here, it is too specific for nothing !!
    spyOn(ServiceA, 'createOperator').and.returnValue(of(response));
    const submitSpy = spyOn(component, 'onSubmit').and.callThrough();
    const toastSpy = spyOn(toast, 'notifyAction')
      .and
      .callThrough();

    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.onSubmit();

    // !! Add this log
    console.log('!! Making Assertion !!');
    expect(ServiceA.createOperator).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(toastSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Make sure you see `!! Here !!` before `!! Making Assertion !!`.

You may be facing an asynchronous issue and it can maybe solved with `fakeAsync/tick`.

```
// !! Add fakeAsync here
fit('should create operator', fakeAsync(() => {
    ...
    component.onSubmit();
    
    tick(); // !! Add tick here to ensure asynchronous activities are done 
            // before carrying on with the test

  }));
```

You can research more about `fakeAsync/tick`.